# Unable to call sp_start_job from website only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, permissions

I have an agent job that I'm trying to use to kick off an SSIS package via a web page. I have configured my web site running in an application pool as user X.

When I invoke sp_start_job as use X from SSMS it successfully starts the job.

When I use my web page to invoke sp_start_job permission is denied.

They user is an administrator locally, and a member of the sysadmin role.

What is preventing successfully invoking sp_start_job from the website?

Comment: does it have proper permissions in msdb ? [Members of SQLAgentUserRole and SQLAgentReaderRole can only start jobs that they own. Members of SQLAgentOperatorRole can start all local jobs including those that are owned by other users.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx)

Comment: All relevant points and verified.

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm with a Profiler trace which credentials are attempting to execute sp_start_job? I'm curious if it's the credentials of the client using the browser or the underlying application pool. If the account in question has sysadmin, it should already have the permissions to execute jobs.

Comment: From what I read, it might be the credentials the Agent service runs under. I'm going to try and get that changed observe the results.